# Focus on Disabled MenuItem. WPF

Tags: wpf, menuitem

How can I select some MenuItem when it is

```
IsEnabled="false"
```

I want to be able to select this item via keyboard's arrows.

Comment: Convention is that disabled items are not available - because they're disabled, there is little value in being able to select them!  Why do you want to be able to do this?

Comment: What is "some autotests?"  If you mean you have an automated test that is accessing the menus via the keyboard, then perhaps there is a better way of writing that test.  Certainly if that's the case, it would seem sensible to *not* break accepted UX paradigm in order to serve a badly-written test.

Comment: @DanPuzey Any sane man would agree. If you need to select it, then it shouldn't be disabled.

Comment: @Erode: true, but how many sane programmers did you ever meet? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You should bind the property of `IsEnabled`  to    Keyboard events .

Comment: This is not a very good answer: it's not clear what you mean and there is no example to help explain.  For example: which keyboard events would you bind to?  How would you set `IsEnabled` in response to that event?